# When to use OpenGL at iOS

Tags: ios, graphics, opengl-es

I am planning to develop a game which is actually a 2D collect'em up style game. There will be not much real time graphic synthesis, mostly there will be sprites floating around.

I know what I ask does not have a "%100 right" answer, but just want to hear opinions, when do you recommend using OpenGL, when to go straight with moving NSObjects on the screen with animations?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IMO it is always better to use OpenGL for graphics: moving, resizing, other transformation. And I suggest not to start from scratch but use some existing solution like http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/

Comment: may using cocos cause any problems with the app store? in the future?

Comment: Most probably not. If you look at cocos site, hundreds of applications and games are using it.

Answer (score -1):

OpenGL is a 3D API, so if you are writing a 3D app then it is your only rational solution. If you are writing a 2D app, you would be better off using CoreGraphics as 2D animations are well supported and it is really quite easy to work with. Much easier than OpenGL at any rate. For example, rendering text is easy in a 2D app using UIKit and CoreGraphics but it is not trivial in OpenGL.